# Why does Mathematica not seem to know that $i^x$ cannot be equal to $0$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am experiencing a curious behaviour of `Simplify` when handling expressions involving powers of $\mathbf{i}$, such as $\mathbf{i}^x$ where $x$ is unknown.

For example, when I take the equation `2^x a == 0`, and I ask Mathematica to simplify it for me by calling `Simplify[2^x a == 0]`, it rightly answers that the original equation is equivalent to `a==0`; hence clearly Mathematica's `Simplify` "knows" that taking a power of something non-zero cannot produce a zero. However, if I ask about `I^x a == 0`, then the result of `Simplify` is merely `I^x a == 0`, i.e. what I started with. This remains true after adding the assumption that $x$ is an integer or changing `Simplify` to `FullSimplify` (i.e. `FullSimplify[I^( x) a == 0, Assumptions -> {Element[x, Integers]}]`. It would be much more convenient if

This is obviously not a serious problem, but it can be a nuisance when I need to simplify a number of equations and would like to quickly see the result in a relatively uncluttered form. Also, I am curious about why things work the way they do, i.e. why complex powers are treated so much differently than real powers. Thank you for any solution to the problem,  and/or explanation of this phenomenon. (A solution would be a way to "teach" Mathematica to eliminate factors like `I^( x)` in equations like `I^( x)*(something)==0`).

Comment: Well, I think in your example the two problems are mathematically different. As $x$ goes to $-\infty$, $i^x$ certainly takes the values $1$ and $-1$ infinitely often (for $x$ congruent to $4$ and $2$ modulo $4$, respectively). After replacing $I$ by $2I$ in your example, the limit comes out as $0$.

Comment: On V 9.01, I get `Simplify[2^x a == 0]`  as `2^x a ==0` not `a==0` ? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TwxvC.png)

Comment: @Nasser: I'm using V 8.0. I didn't realise this would differ between versions.

Comment: Now in V11.3, `I^(1000. I)` underflows to `0. + 0. I`, not that that should count, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can actually 'teach' `Simplify` using the option `TransformationFunctions`.

```
dropPows[Power[_?NumericQ, _] a_ == 0] := a == 0

Simplify[I^x a == 0, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, dropPows}]
(* a == 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as I was hoping it would.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is a difference in versions (9.0.1), but when I do:

```
FullSimplify[2^x a == 0, x \[Element] Reals]
a == 0
```

Replacing `2` with `I` gives the same answer

```
FullSimplify[I^x a == 0, x \[Element] Reals]
a == 0
```

Comment: The take-away lesson here, which I think is the important point, is that you need to `Simplify` that `x` is a number.  Seems cleaner than a special transformation function.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample, of arguable importance:

```
FunctionExpand[I^x] /. x -> DirectedInfinity[I]
(*  0  *)
```

Which shows why [@bill s's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35119/4999) idea of restricting `x` to a number might help simplify the expression.   I don't know if `FullSimplify` was necessary back then, but in V11 the following works:

```
Simplify[I^x a == 0, x ∈ Complexes]
(*  a == 0  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

While `TransformationFunction` is really the way to go, a quick way is to use replacement rules directly:

```
I^x a == 0 /. {Power[_?NumericQ, _] x_ == 0 :> x == 0}
```

> a == 0